# Why is my Site.UrlRewriter implementation not affecting URLFOR()

Tags: apex, visualforce, force.com-sites, urlfor, urlrewriter

I have a Visualforce Page running on a Force.com Site that looks like this:

```
<apex:page standardController="Page__c" extensions="RootTemplateExtension">
    {!URLFOR($Page.Master, null, ["id"="a00b000000IovF1"])}
</apex:page>
```

And I've got a `Site.UrlRewriter` implementation that looks like this:

```
global List<PageReference> generateUrlFor(List<PageReference> salesforceRefs) {
    //TODO bulkify this

    List<PageReference> friendlyRefs = new List<PageReference>();
    for (PageReference salesforceRef : salesforceRefs) {
        String salesforceUrl = salesforceRef.getUrl();
        Map<String,String> salesforceParams = salesforceUrl.getParameters();

        //note URLFOR does not output '/apex' prefix in context of Force.com Sites
        String master = Page.Master.getUrl().replace('/apex', '');

        if (salesforceUrl.startsWith(master) && salesforceParams.containsKey('id')) {
            Id pageId = salesforceUrl.getParameters().get('id');
            Page__c page = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Page__c WHERE Id = :pageId];

            PageReference friendlyRef = new PageReference('/' + page.Name);
            friendlyRefs.add(friendlyRef);
        }
    }

    return friendlyRefs;
}
```

**I've even got a TEST that shows this should work**

```
static testmethod void testGenerateUrlForSummary() {
    //arrange rewriter and page
    Site.UrlRewriter rewriter = new UrlRewriter();
    Page__c page = new Page__c(Name = 'Summary');
    insert page;

    //arrange url ('/ns__Master?id=a01000000000AAA')
    String url = System.Page.Master.getUrl().replace('/apex', ''); //drop prefix
    PageReference salesforceRef = new PageReference(url);
    salesforceRef.getParameters().put('id', page.Id);

    //act
    PageReference friendlyRef = rewriter.generateUrlFor(new List<PageReference>{salesforceRef})[0];

    //assert
    String expectedUrl = '/Summary';
    String actualUrl = friendlyRef.getUrl();
    System.assertEquals(expectedUrl, actualUrl, 'Summary url not generated.');
}
```

But for the life of me I can't see it happen in the actual Force.com Site. I've carpet bombed the code with `System.debug` but all I can eyeball is that `startsWith` is not true as expected.

Any ideas?

Comment: just a suggestion did you try startsWithIgnoreCase? could be a case sensitivity issue?

Comment: Thanks @rao! You are correct, Apex PageReference is generated with lowercase `m` first letter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a Force.com Site, the implementation of URLFOR() and Page.Master.getUrl() differ:

`URLFOR()` returns an all-lowercase string without /apex prefix.

`PageReference.getUrl` returns a first-letter-capitalized string with /apex prefix.

```
public class UrlForController {
    public String getApexUrl() {
        return Page.MaStEr.getUrl();
    }
}

<apex:page controller="UrlForController">
    <pre>
        //all lowercase "/master"
        {!URLFOR($Page.MaStEr)}

        //capitalizes first letter only "/apex/Master"
        {!ApexUrl}
    </pre>
</apex:page>
```